# Where Does Gauss-Hermite Quadrature Get Its Name From?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I am trying to learn more about Numerical Integration using Gauss-Hermite Quadrature

As I understand, Gauss-Hermite Quadrature is a numerical integration technique that is used to approximate integral of some function $f(x)$ and is given by:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{-x^2} dx \approx \sum_{i=1}^n w_i f(x_i)$$

where:

- $n$ is the number of quadrature points
- $w_i$ are the weights
- $x_i$ are the quadrature points.

The weights and quadrature points can be computed using the roots of the $n$-th order Hermite polynomial:

$$H_n(x) = (-1)^n e^{x^2} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} e^{-x^2}$$

The $n$ roots of $H_n(x)$ are denoted by $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$, and the corresponding weights are given by:

$$w_i = \frac{2^{n-1} n! \sqrt{\pi}}{n^2 [H_{n-1}(x_i)]^2}$$

Putting this all together, we can then numerically approximate the integral of $f(x)$ using Gauss-Hermite Quadrature.

**My Question:** Based on this, I have not seen any mention of "Gauss" in this algorithm. I have only seen mention of "Hermite".

Can someone please explain where exactly is the relevance of "Gaussian" in the Gauss-Hermite Quadrature? Does this somehow method somehow rely on the Gaussian Probability Distribution in the background?

Thanks!

Comment: The Gaussian distribution is a constant times $e^{-x^2}$, so isn't that the reason?

Comment: 'Gauss' is included because the technique of choosing _both_ abscissas and weights optimally  is credited to him. Hence Gauss-Laguerre, Gauss-Jacobi, Gauss-Hermite, etc.

Comment: Gauss was incredibly productive in many different areas and has lots of things named after him.  Gaussian quadrature is not related to Gaussian distributions, or Gaussian elimination, or ... Well here's a [list of things named after Gauss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_things_named_after_Carl_Friedrich_Gauss0.)

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I think you meant to link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_things_named_after_Carl_Friedrich_Gauss

Comment: @ Randall: thank you for your reply! Can you please elaborate?